# How to stop the list, missing number from user enter

Tags: python, list

I'm doing this exercise:

> In your main function, you need to keep asking user to enter an
> integer, then store those integers in a list. Once the user decides to
> stop entering, the function should print out all the integers from the
> list, and also find the largest number in that list. If the user did
> not enter any number, you should print out “Your list is empty”.

I tried to code it but I got stuck on print "Your list is empty". I don't know where to put the statement.

And when the user enters the number, the list will come out missing the first number the user entered.

```
def main():
    user_list = []
    
    user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')
    
    while user_num != 'x':
        
        user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')

        if user_num != 'x' :
            user_list.append(user_num)

        if user_list == []:
            print('Your List is empty')
            exit()
        
    
    index = 0
    while index < len(user_list):
        user_list[index] = int(user_list[index])
        index += 1
    
    print ('Here is the list of the numberyou entered:')
    
        
    print (*user_list, sep = '\n')

    largest = max(user_list)

    print ('The largest number in your listis: ',largest)
main()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
def main():
    user_list = []

    while True:
        user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')

        if user_num == 'x':
            break  # exit the "while" loop

        user_list.append(user_num)

    # this is after the loop:

    if user_list == []:
        print('Your List is empty')
        exit()

    # user_list = list(map(int, user_list))
    for index in range(len(user_list)):  # range is a list-like thing of 0, 1, 2, 3... up to the length of the list
        user_list[index] = int(user_list[index])

    print ('Here is the list of numbers you entered:')

    print (*user_list, sep='\n')

    largest = max(user_list)

    print ('The largest number in your lists: ', largest)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, change:

```
while user_num != 'x':
    
    user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')

    if user_num != 'x' :
        user_list.append(user_num)

    if user_list == []:
        print('Your List is empty')
        exit()
```

To:

```
while True:
    
    user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')

    if user_num != 'x' and user_num:
        user_list.append(user_num)

    elif not user_list:
        print('Your List is empty')
        exit()
    else:
        break
```

---

---

---

Here is the optimized code:

```
def main():
    user_list = []
    while True:
        user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')
        if user_num != 'x' and user_num:
            user_list.append(int(user_num))
        elif not user_list:
            print('Your List is empty')
            exit()
        else:
            break
    print ('Here is the list of the numbers you entered:')
    print (*user_list, sep = '\n')
    largest = max(user_list)
    print ('The largest number in your list is: ', largest)
    
main()
```

Comment: This is what I got when I switch It around:                                                                                  Enter an integer or enter x to stop: x
Here is the list of the numberyou entered:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yenvivian/Desktop/Python HW/numlist.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/yenvivian/Desktop/Python HW/numlist.py", line 30, in main
    largest = max(user_list)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Answer (score 0):

```
if user_list == []:
    print('Your List is empty')
    exit()
```

You should write this portion outside the while loop. Like this

```
def main():
    user_list = []
    
    user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')
    
    while user_num != 'x':
        
        user_num = input('Enter an integer or enter x to stop: ')

        if user_num != 'x' :
            user_list.append(user_num)

    if user_list == []:
        print('Your List is empty')
```